# Getting UIButton instance from NIB (Without interaction)

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton, xib, nib

I was wondering how to grab an instance of a UIButton without interacting with it. I have placed a button in my xib, and just want to be able to get it's position in code. I have created an IBOutlet and linked them up, but when I look at the position of the IBOutlet it is set to 0,0.

Any help is much appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Elliott

Comment: You may be calling it too early. From which method are you accessing the position?

Comment: I am accessing it after a button is released, so all the positions should definitely be worked out by then.

Comment: It isn't the positions that I was concerned about. It's the bindings between the UI elements and the IBOutlets. It looks like you have actually wired up the button to its IBOutlet via the XIB editor. Does the IBOutlet variable have a non-nil value when you try to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set `tag` property of that but button, say 1001, and for example in `viewDidLoad` method you can get that button by :

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
  {
      UIButton *temp = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1001];
      NSLog(@"%f",temp.frame.origin.x);
      NSLog(@"%f",temp.frame.origin.y);
  }
```

Hope it helps you...

Comment: Question specifies IBOutlet exists. This would be the answer getting the information without an outlet.

Comment: I know I originally specified using an IBOutlet, but I guess as long as I can hook that up in some way then it should all be fine. It's probably not the best practice but I am setting my IBOutlet using the above code now.

Comment: "without interacting" I presumed without a user interacting with the button to cause an event which would cause a reference of the button to be sent via an IBAction. Not as getting the information from a button without using the IBOutlet I have set up to reference the button.